# Date picker dialog issue in android 5 lolipop

Tags: android, android-datepicker

[image]

> I can't show the another date in android 5 lollipop.

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                        }
                    };

DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(activity, R.style.DatePickerDialogStyle, onDateSetListener, 2019, 9, 19);

datePickerDialog.show();
```

I am use below datepicker style

```
 <style name="DatePickerDialogStyle">
        <item name="showTitle">false</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: you need to share code for the date picker that you have used

Comment: please share code what you have done so far ?

Comment: I guess is because of the style.

Comment: Hello @Nidhi can you please share DatePickerDialogStyle style ? so it will help us to diagnose the issue

Comment: I edited code please check.

Comment: @Nidhi remove R.style.DatePickerDialogStyle from DatePickerDialog and see result what it will be

Answer (score 1):

- I think it's a Style issue.

**Just check it**

In my code, I have added custom style which name is "DatePickerDialogStyle"

In style.xml file add this style:-

```
<style name="DatePickerDialogStyle">
    <item name="showTitle">false</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

> **Example :-**

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(activityName.this, R.style.DatePickerDialogStyle, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
```

I hope It will work.

Comment: @NidhiSavaliya please don't forget to give it true.

Answer (score 0):

You need have to just remove theme in Object of `DatePickerDialog`

your object of `DatePickerDialog` initialisation will be like this

```
DatePickerDialog(getViewActivity(), onDateSetListener,  Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
```

Let me know if it working or not i haven't check this in Lollipop device

Comment: But i have set app theme in datepicker dialog so how can i remove it.