# Android DatePickerDialog is not working on Android 5

Tags: android, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm working on an app, on registration form, the user needs to enter his birthday. I used a DatePickerDialog. The app works fine on my phone and on emulator but when i tested it on an old phone (android 5) the app stop functionning when i want to select the date.

This is my XML code

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="BirthDatePicker"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is my java code

```
public void BirthDatePicker(View v) throws ParseException {
  final DatePickerDialog[] picker = new DatePickerDialog[1];
    final TextInputEditText eText;
    eText= findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    //eText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    // date picker dialog  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener
    picker[0] = new DatePickerDialog(RegisterActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                eText.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                setDate( dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                }
            }, year, month, day);

    picker[0].show();
}
```

setter :

```
 public void setDate(String date) {
        mDate = date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my comment in answer field because of this restriction: 'You must have 50 reputation to comment'.

Paste the logcat details for the actual device.

I think it has something to do with the 'style' issue.

Do check out [Date picker dialog issue in android 5 lolipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022135/date-picker-dialog-issue-in-android-5-lolipop)